# Creating a Azure.Storage.Queues client that can handle multiple queues

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I'm migrating my code from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue` to `Azure.Storage.Queues`. In my app, I wrapped all queue operations I use in a `MyQueueClient` class. The old way of creating a queue client was as follows:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
CloudQueueClient client = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
```

Because I have multiple queues, this approach worked nicely for me. In the new approach, it looks like I need to pass the queue name as one of the parameters to create a queue client -- see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet#create-the-queue-service-client

```
QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);
```

So, I'm a bit confused here. Does this mean, I have to create a separate queue client for each queue that I work with? Say, I have 3 queues, does it mean I have to create 3 queue clients? Doesn't seem to make sense. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
        QueueServiceClient queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(connectionString);
```

then you can use the methods based on `queueServiceClient`(note that it may have some limitations compared to the old one).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this one too :-)